# RecyclerView showing only first 2 items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> The problem is the App is showing Images only the first 2 items from the JSON response. Rest are  not shown.

> This is the JSON response i am showing in the App:

```
{
"msg": true,
"src": [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "banner_name": "https://testproject1.indigierp.com/images/banners/promo1.jpg",
        "user_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-09-22 21:46:04",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "banner_name": "https://testproject1.indigierp.com/images/banners/promo3.jpg",
        "user_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-09-22 21:46:16",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "banner_name": "https://testproject1.indigierp.com/images/banners/promo4.jpg",
        "user_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-09-22 21:46:28",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "banner_name": "https://testproject1.indigierp.com/images/banners/promo4.jpg",
        "user_id": "1",
        "created_at": "2021-09-23 03:30:41",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    },
  
]
```

}

> This is MainActivity code :

```
 final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, BANNER_URL, null, response -> {

        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

            try {
             
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("src");
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);                 
                String bannerName = jsonObject.getString("banner_name");          
                sliderModelList.add(new SliderModel(bannerName));
                sliderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

> This is adapter code:

```
      @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final SliderModel sliderModel = sliderModelList.get(position);
   Picasso.getInstance(mCtx)
                .load(sliderModel.getBanner_name())
                .into(holder.homeImage);

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sliderModelList.size();

    }
```

> Slider Model class :

```
  public SliderModel(String banner_name) {
    this.banner_name = banner_name;
}

public String getBanner_name() {
    return banner_name;
}
```

> What wrong am I doing. Please guide with your solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you debug i? What's the size sliderModelList?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. Its inside scrollview

Comment: @m0skit0  list size is only 2, I dunno why

Comment: Then that's why it's showing 2 elements on the recycler view. Did you consider using a JSON parser that directly creates the objects for you instead of doing it manually (e.g. Gson or Jackson)?

Comment: used Volley to parse JSON. created Model class as shown on the code above

Comment: Did you debug jsonArray size?

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, its showing all the data